# Form in Firefox not shown if specific id-text, but exists in source code

Tags: html, forms, firefox, debian

I build a form (for cookieconsent). On the Firefox an my Debian machine, this form is not be renderd. If I click inspect element, the form and all contents are not shown in the inspector -> source. But if I click "show source", the complete form is in the source.
Now I figured the following out:
The form has the id "formCookieconsent". If I rename the id to "bla", the form will be shown. So I tried more:

```
id: "cookie" -> don't work
id: "consent" -> don't work
id: "xxxcookiexxx" -> don't work
id: "xxxconsentxxx" -> don't work
id: "kookie" -> work
id: "cooxkie" -> work
id: "konsent" -> work
```

Obviously, the form will not be renderd, if the id contains one of the strings "cookie" or "consent".
First I tried it with Firefox 68.1.1.0esr 6-bit on Debian Buster. The I updated Debian, now it is Firefox 78.3.0esr 64-bit but the problem is the same.
I have more Debian machines here, with the same Firefox without the problem.
Can someone explain me that? :-)

Comment: Do you have browser extensions activated?

Comment: You got it:-) I don't remember that I installed a Cookie-popup blocker add-on. At the moment, I want to try to disable all Add-ons and found this blocker Add-on :-)